# Want to create a script that removes all screenshots from desktop

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix

I want to have a script that I can run to remove all screenshots from my desktop.
All the screenshots have a name starting with "Screen Shot".
I tried using this;

```
find /Users/Mht/Desktop/ -name "Screen*" -exec rm{} -i \;
```

(My username is "Mht"...) this returns:

```
find: rm/Users/Mht/Desktop//Screen Shot 2017-05-09 at 19.08.59.png: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: FYI, the default `rm` in macOS requires options come *before* positional arguments, so `rm "Screen Shot 1" -i` is going to delete the file, then give you an error message stating that `-i` doesn't exist. You'll need `rm -i {}` instead. (If you are somehow using GNU `rm` instead, then the order is less important.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a space between `rm` and `{}` (if you look closely at the error message this becomes apparent, but it's not immediately obvious, I admit).

I just tried the following and it worked for me:

```
find ~/Desktop -type f -name "Screen Shot*" -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do you have an explanation for what the "{}" behind the command to execute means?

Comment: It's a placeholder that `find` replaces with the name of the current file when it calls `rm`. However, you can use `find ~/Desktop -type f -name "Screen Shot*" -delete` instead; it more efficient, since it doesn't have to run the `rm` command once for every file.

Comment: @chepner: good point about `-delete` - I didn't change it in my example though, as it seems the OP might want the interactive option with `rm` (`rm -i`).

Answer (score 3):

You can always write a Python script for this, which is fairly easy:

```
import os
os.chdir('/Users/Mht/Desktop')
filenames = [filename for filename in os.listdir() if filename.startswith("Screen")]
for f in filenames:
    os.remove(f)
```

Of course if you absolutely want to do it in a bash script you can always just use rm with a wildcard, as in `rm -i /Users/Mht/Desktop/Screen*`. Of course, as noted in a comment, it is always much safer to be as specific as possible, so it is even better to have something like  `rm -i /Users/Mht/Desktop/Screen\ Shot*`.

Comment: or `rm -i Screen*` to get the interactive the OP wanted; or slightly safer `rm -i "Screen Shot"*`